# NotFoundHttpException with Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I've just installed [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) on Windows and unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 1093:

in Application.php line 1093
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('0')) in Application.php line 1063
at Application->dispatch(null) in Application.php line 1006
at Application->run() in index.php line 28
```

What may be the problem here?

Comment: Do you access the application with `/public` at the end? (like `http://localhost/lumen/public`)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

On your `index.php` file. Change this line

```
$app->run();
```

Into:

```
$app->run($app->request);
```

### Update

Using `make` method is faster than accessing class alias via array access.

This one also works:

```
$app->run(
    $app->make('request')
);
```

Comment: @DanielFaria Because [`run`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L1035) method takes one argument, which can be `null`. Then, application will `dispatch` the route via [`dispatch`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L1077) method. When the request is null, then request pathInfo will be parsed in [`pathInfo`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L1359) method. You'll find something interisting here.

Answer (score 70):

The problem was solved by changing the

```
$app->run();
```

in /public/index.php to

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);
```

Comment: This really answered my question... Nice

Comment: save the day, this should apply on fresh copy, bcz fresh copy only contain `$app->run();`

Comment: why we need to add the http/request? API will work fine with these lines?

Comment: @SafoorSafdar If you put your Lumen App inside a subfolder (relative to your web server),  Lumen will fail because the `getPathInfo` method return wrong path. If you want to use real `getPathInfo`, you should add extra arguments in `run()` method. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L1077) and [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L1359).

Comment: Laravel is great, but sometimes it's very annoying how irrationally stubborn Taylor can be about things such as the sub-folder deal, even when it requires essentially no effort on his end. Also, doing this is officially not supported, and may stop working if the API changes.

Comment: Really helped me on IIS7. Thanks a lot.