# Lumen unpredictable output

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Recently, I installed `lumen` (5.0.4) mfw and ran into an issue with page load on default configuration. I have unpredictable behavior of page load process.

Sometimes it loads okay but sometimes instead of loading I am getting a download dialog with zero size unnamed file or it throws an exception like

```
NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 1109:
```

(At first, I want to say that other non lumen/laravel sites work fine) Server configuration:

- Apache 2.4.12
- PHP 5.6.7-1
- Zend Engine v2.6.0 with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev

I think the problem is with `php` working through `php-fpm` because with `fcgi` configuration it seems to work well.

I tried [NotFoundHttpException with Lumen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen) but that didn't help me.

Comment: Inspect Apache's error log for that vhost. It will contain information about what went wrong.

Comment: This is almost certainly not a problem with Lumen. It sounds like PHP-FPM is crashing and since Apache cannot pass this request on to FPM simply returns the file unprocessed.

Comment: What does your FPM log say?

Comment: I'm more interested in the php-fpm log as well. It should be located in `/var/log/php-fpm.log` on most distros.

Comment: NotFoundHttpException indicates that no route matches the request. Maybe something with the URL rewriting? You could modify the exception handler to print the request details to the app log. http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors This may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Sound like something with php-fpm as others already commented; you could also test the alternative .htaccess that the documentation provides (http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls) – could perhaps be an issue with some of your Apache modules?

Comment: Show us your routes and an example of the path the page you are accessing that has issues. What cases does it fail?

Comment: Problem was in server configuration, I reinstall apache & php-fpm and now lumen works fine

Comment: Can you mark question as answered please, even if you answer your own question.

Comment: it may helps you. Simple tutorial about lumen http://wsnippets.com/create-rest-api-using-lumen-micro-framework-by-laravel/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotFoundHttpException with Lumen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen)

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue, after hours of research and debug, I fixed the issue.

If you are doing something like this ...

```
$app->run($httpRequest);
```

instead do ...

```php
$httpRequest = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($httpRequest);
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `$app->run();` to `$app->run($app['request']);` in public/index.php (Lumen 5.2)