# lumen NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php

Tags: php, lumen

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen). (Please clink on the link before you vote to close it under the duplicate tag.) But none of the solutions have worked for me.

I can access `/` without any errors. But when I try to use a get request to login I get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException
in RoutesRequests.php (line 594)
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(0))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 532)
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
in RoutesRequests.php (line 781)
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 534)
at Application->dispatch(null)
in RoutesRequests.php (line 475)
at Application->run()
in index.php (line 28)
```

`index.php (line 28)` points to `$app->run();`

Here is my code for the login form page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>notes!</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('../assets/css/main.css') }}"> -->
    <style>
            body {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        .banner {
            margin: 100px auto;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #333333;
        }

        .loginContainer {
            width:30%;
            margin: 50px auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-color: #333333;
            border:2px;
            border-radius:10px;
        }

        form {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 50px;
        }

        form input {
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        form button {
            display: block;
            width: 314px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: none;
            background-color: #3366ff;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- <div class="navbar">
         <ul>
         <li>Login</li>
         <li>About Me!</li>
         </ul>
         </div> -->
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>Welcome to notes!</h1>
        <h4>Add notes, to-do lists and more!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="loginContainer">
        <form class="signin" method="get" action="/login/">
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for `routes.php`:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return view('welcome');
});

$app->get('login/','UsersController@authenticate');
$app->post('todo/','TodoController@store');
$app->get('todo/', 'TodoController@index');
$app->get('todo/{id}/', 'TodoController@show');
$app->put('todo/{id}/', 'TodoController@update');
$app->delete('todo/{id}/', 'TodoController@destroy');

?>
```

Here is the `UsersController.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Users;

class UsersController extends Controller

{

  public function __construct()

   {

//        $this->middleware('auth:api');

   }

   /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */

   public function authenticate(Request $request)

   {

       $this->validate($request, [

       'email' => 'required',

       'password' => 'required'

        ]);

      $user = Users::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

     if(Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)){

          $apikey = base64_encode(str_random(40));

          Users::where('email', $request->input('email'))->update(['api_key' => "$apikey"]);;

          return response()->json(['status' => 'success','api_key' => $apikey]);

      }else{

          return response()->json(['status' => 'fail'],401);

      }

   }

}    

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotFoundHttpException with Lumen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen)

Comment: Then you need to share some of your code

Comment: @GovindSamrow added code to the question

Comment: @VineetKaushik answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339633/6588347) is correct. Lumen routing is somehow more strict than its mother Laravel :) Also, please use POST method on your login form for security and/or any other forms that involve data storing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route first argument is trimmed with '/'

Fix to form action:
/login/ -> /login

```
<form class="signin" method="get" action="/login">
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the trailing backslash in your `action` attribute but here's some points to consider:

**First** of all I do not know why you want to use [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) request for login form since the credentials you send to the server will appear in the url in the user's browser and this kind of info should be safe especially the **Password** - another thing why don't you use [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) engine to make your views more elegant but it's ok we can use the native php syntax.

- to get the correct path to the `/login` route we will make use of [url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url).
- then we will change the method to [post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm) which suits perfect for what we want to achieve : send data to our server without being displayed in the user's browser so our form will look like this:

  `<form class="signin" method="post" action="<?=url('/login');?>">
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  </form>`
- another thing i have added the [name](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) attribute which is important when retrieving the form values.
- and also we will use `post` method in `routes/web.php` like so:

  `$app->post('/login','UsersController@authenticate');`

Answer (score -1):

I think you `.htaccess` file missing, add .`htaccess` file in public directory and assign read permission to `apache`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```