# Lumen Regular Expression Constraints throw NotFoundHttpException

Tags: lumen

I have a list of routes, some are using parameters and everything is working correctly.
My problem happen when I try to constrain the parameter (to check the it is valid before executing my controller).

Following the documentation I did it this way :

```
    $router->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/user/{userId:[a-z0-9]+}', 'UserController@userByUserIdGet');
});
```

But all I receive is a NotFoundHttpException meaning that it doesn't match my route.

I can't see where my mistake is. Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error you recieve, if your route doensn't exists is a MethodNotAllowedHttpException - your code and the regex for your route do work correctly, so I am assuming, that your error could have an other reason.

Maybe you should check this:
[NotFoundHttpException with Lumen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen)

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering my question, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. The MethodNotAllowedHttpException is only thrown if for example I call a post method where I only have a GET route. If I fallback to my route without the regex it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OK stupid error from my side.
I'm passing UUID as userID parameter... AND they have a dash in them.
So my regex should be this one

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () use ($router) {
   $router->get('/user/{userId:[a-z0-9\-]+}', 'UserController@userByUserIdGet');
```

});