# Not Found Http Exception Lumen 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using

Lumen Version: 6.0.3 
PHP Version: 7.3.0 
Database Driver & Version: MySQL 
Description:
I am creating API for my application in the lumen as backend. But after test with postman, I am getting response **NotFoundHttpException**.

This is my routes

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

// public routes
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () use ($router) {

    $router->post('register', 'UsersController@register');
    $router->post('login', ['uses'=>'AuthController@authenticate']);

});

// auth routes
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/auth', 'middleware'=>'jwt'], function () use ($router) {

    $router->post('create-course', 'CourseController@create_course');

});
```

I have also tried this solution but failed to run my application. Please follow the link:

[NotFoundHttpException with Lumen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen)

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which route are you trying to access, and with GET or POST?

Comment: with every route, i'm getting this exception.

Comment: what webserver are you using?

Comment: This could have 20 different causes. Just type `php artisan route:list` (not sure if this works for Lumen) and it should list your routes. If it doesnt work, go check your `RouteServiceProvider` how your routes are being loaded (i.e. middleware or prefix settings).